# Beginner Python: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute

Tags: python, list, class, dictionary, attributeerror

The error says:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'cost'
```

I am trying to get a simple profit calculation to work using the following class to handle a dictionary of bicycles:

```
class Bike(object):
    def __init__(self, name, weight, cost):
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight
        self.cost = cost

bikes = {
    # Bike designed for children"
    "Trike": ["Trike", 20, 100],
    # Bike designed for everyone"
    "Kruzer": ["Kruzer", 50, 165]
    }
```

When I try to calculate profit with my for statement, I get the attribute error.

```
# Markup of 20% on all sales
margin = .2
# Revenue minus cost after sale
for bike in bikes.values():
    profit = bike.cost * margin
```

First, I don't know why it is referring to a list, and everything seems to be defined, no?

Comment: You are not creating `Bike` objects with the `[]` syntax.  You are creating lists.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Consider:

```
class Bike(object):
    def __init__(self, name, weight, cost):
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight
        self.cost = cost

bikes = {
    # Bike designed for children"
    "Trike": Bike("Trike", 20, 100),      # <--
    # Bike designed for everyone"
    "Kruzer": Bike("Kruzer", 50, 165),    # <--
    }

# Markup of 20% on all sales
margin = .2
# Revenue minus cost after sale
for bike in bikes.values():
    profit = bike.cost * margin
    print(profit)
```

Output:

```
33.0
20.0
```

The difference is that in your `bikes` dictionary, you're initializing the values as lists `[...]`.  Instead, it looks like the rest of your code wants `Bike` instances.  So create `Bike` instances: `Bike(...)`.

As for your error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'cost'
```

this will occur when you try to call `.cost` on a `list` object.  Pretty straightforward, but we can figure out what happened by looking at where you call `.cost` -- in this line:

```
profit = bike.cost * margin
```

This indicates that at least one `bike` (that is, a member of `bikes.values()` is a list).  If you look at where you defined `bikes` you can see that the values were, in fact, lists.  So this error makes sense.

But since *your class* has a cost attribute, it looked like you were trying to use `Bike` instances as values, so I made that little change:

```
[...] -> Bike(...)
```

and you're all set.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained the difference between your code and OP's.

Comment: @Kevin edited it after I posted it -- actually going to revise it again to explain the initial error.

Answer (score 6):

They are lists because you type them as lists in the dictionary:

```
bikes = {
    # Bike designed for children"
    "Trike": ["Trike", 20, 100],
    # Bike designed for everyone"
    "Kruzer": ["Kruzer", 50, 165]
    }
```

You should use the bike-class instead:

```
bikes = {
    # Bike designed for children"
    "Trike": Bike("Trike", 20, 100),
    # Bike designed for everyone"
    "Kruzer": Bike("Kruzer", 50, 165)
    }
```

This will allow you to get the cost of the bikes with bike.cost as you were trying to.

```
for bike in bikes.values():
    profit = bike.cost * margin
    print(bike.name + " : " + str(profit))
```

This will now print:

```
Kruzer : 33.0
Trike : 20.0
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass the values of the dict into the `Bike` constructor before using like that. Or, see the `namedtuple` -- seems more in line with what you're trying to do.